# Buildfire: How to attach an action to a push notification with the Public API

Tags: buildfire

I am using the Buildfire Public API to send push notifications. Is it possible to attach an action to the push notification via the Public API, similiar to how it works when sending a notification in CP?

I don't see anything on the Swagger page that allows this. I am looking for a way to have the notification open up to a certain part of the app (e.g. deeplink)

Answer (score 0):

Buildfire doesn't support PN actions via Public API yet.

Comment: Is there a plan to implement this? This is a pretty important feature for our app